# Pinch-to-zoom in HTML emails

Tags: email, html, stock-email-app

In the standard browser you can zoom in/out (by pinching or with the buttons.)
But in the standard Mail app (at least in Android 2.3.7) it does not work when viewing an HTML email message.

Is there a way to enable this?  (Or is there a 3rd-party mail app that does?)